# how to convert char in octal format without standart C functions like print(f)

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

Need to convert code of char into octal. Maybe to convert char into decimal first and then to octal,if it would be more easy. It doesn't matter.

```
char c; // equal 'd' or '\n' for example
int d=...;//something to change
```

`printf("%o",c)` will be good variant,but I can't use standart C function. Only own implementation of converting.
Please,write here some better implements or your own implement.

how printf() do it for (%o)

```
printf(ul, 8)
{
    /* hold a long in base 8 */
    char *p, buf[(sizeof(long) * NBBY / 3) + 1];

    p = buf;
    do {
        *p++ = "0123456789abcdef"[ul % base];
    } while (ul /= base);
    do {
        putchar(*--p);
    } while (p > buf);
}
```

but i dont want to use putchar(), want just to save.

Comment: How about you show your attempt?

Comment: Why would you convert char into octal?In fact,what does it even mean?And do make your question a little clearer.

Comment: Code of char in octal format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decimal and octal are number bases, this only matters when *presenting* a number (or when *inputing* a number); the actual number is generally stored in binary in the computer's memory but this doesn't often matter to typical programs.

In your case, conversion to octal generally involves extracting three bits at a time (since 2<sup>3</sup> is 8). This can be done by masking with the mask `7` (binary `111`), and then shifting. This will get the octal digits in right-to-left order.

Assuming a `char` of 8 bits (which is typical), you're going to be generating 3 octal digits since 3 * 3 = 9. Two digits would only cover 6 bits which is clearly not enough.

That's so few, you can actually "unroll" it:

```
void to_octal(char *buf, unsigned char x)
{
  buf[0] = '0' + ((x >> 6) & 7);
  buf[1] = '0' + ((x >> 3) & 7);
  buf[2] = '0' + (x & 7);
  buf[3] = '\0';
}
```

Note that the above *requires* `buf` to have at least four characters of space available. Usage:

```
const unsigned char x = 212;
char buf[8];

to_octal(buf, x);
printf("%d is %s in octal\n", x, buf);
```

Comment: tnx,but I need to convert ASCI code of char 'i' into octal format

Comment: @AlexZern That's what this does. If you call `to_octal()` with x set to e.g. 'a' (ASCII 97), it will set `buf` to "141".